# Why GCC option -Os is not used during compilation?

Tags: optimization, clang, compiler-flags

Clang warns me,

```
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-Os'
```

During compile with `make`. Why it doesn't accept the optimization flag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-Os` isn't a valid optimization option for (most) `clang` - it's not completely flag-compatible with GCC.

The clang man page is authoritative on what options your particular version accepts (specifically, optimizing by size is not yet a primary concern for LLVM).  Apple has pushed back patches for `-Os` and `-Oz`, but most packages don't include these updates.

Comment: Apple's `clang` is somewhat custom, and the `clang` in Xcode 4.0 claims to support `-Os`, although not in any earlier versions.

Comment: @Eonil: remember than one of the primary reason for CLang to be released using a Berkley-style license is for Apple to maintain a custom version without *having* to port the changes back into the mainline.

Comment: @Matthieu Thanks. I was know that, but I forgot. And now realized it again :)